# Vector object in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, vector

I've noticed that arrays are not declared with specific sizes in swift. I know c++ where this is not the case and to use a dynamic list I need to use a vector object. Is there a certain vector object in swift or do arrays adjust size at runtime?

Comment: Did you have a look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array or https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html ?

Comment: No I did not, I'll check though. Thanks. Should have though of that

Comment: See this page https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/working_with_vectors

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a certain vector object in swift or do arrays adjust size at runtime?

The latter: Any array reserves a well-determined amount of memory to hold its elements. Whenever you append elements to an array, making the array exceed the reserved capacity, **it allocates a larger region of memory**, whose size is a multiple of the  old storage's capacity.

## Why does an array grow its memory exponentially?

Exponential growth is meant to average the time performance of the `append()` (add element(s)) function. Whenever the memory is increased, the elements are copied into the new storage. Of course, when memory reallocation is triggered, the performance of the `append()` function is *significantly* reduced, though this happens less often as the array becomes bigger and bigger.

---

I suggest you to look over the [Array Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array), especially the *"Growing the Size of an Array"* Chapter. If you want to preallocate space in the array, it is good to know of the `reserveCapacity(_:)` method. [Related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27830470/swift-array-capacity-vs-array-count) for more details about `capacity`.